# What i am doing wrong here?

Tags: ajax, this, response

Hey I don't know why $(this) not working in my ajax code.I want to append response in #feedback element.

here is my html structure image

[image]

**AJAX**

```
$("form#userComment").on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url  : "request/postComment.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : new FormData(this),
    dataType : "text",
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    beforeSend : function(http){
        $("#upload").val("Posting..");
        $("#comment").val("");
    },
    success : function(response,status,http){
         var text = response.split(" ");
         $("#upload").val("Post");
        if(text[3] === "'error'"){
            $(".response").html(response);
            $(".response").slideDown();
        }else{         
           $(this).prev().append(response);
        }
    },
    error : function(http,status,error){ 
        $("#comment").val("Post");
        $('.response').html("<span class='error'>Something went wrong</span>");
        $(".response").slideDown();
    }
})
})
```

Comment: It will be not works first you select that feedback div and store it into a global variable and after that you can append html by using that global variable name. Do it like this - 

when submit fire - 
parentElement = $('#feedback');

In Ajax you can write html into this div by this way - 
parentElement.html(<whatever you write just put that html here>)

may be this can help you.